# Failure to install python-chess: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'distclass' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, ssl

I'm trying to install `python-chess` (Python 2.7 on Windows 7).

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Jeroen>pip install python-chess
Collecting python-chess
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may caus
e the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL con
nections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached python-chess-0.13.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\jeroen\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-2eph1o\python-chess\setup.py", line 91, in <module>
        "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 98, in setup
        klass = distclass
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'distclass' referenced before assignment

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\jeroen\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-2eph1o\python-chess\
```

When I rerun `pip install python-chess` once more, the `SNIMissingWarning` doesn't appear any more, but the `UnboundLocalError` is still there.

**Edit**

Answers to the questions in the comments:

```
Python 2.7.3 |EPD_free 7.3-2 (32-bit)| (default, Apr 12 2012, 14:30:37) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "credits", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
>>> import distutils
>>> print distutils.__version__
2.7.3
>>>
```

and `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py` around line 90 looks like this:

```
global _setup_stop_after, _setup_distribution

# Determine the distribution class -- either caller-supplied or
# our Distribution (see below).
klass = distclass
if klass:
    del distclass
else:
    klass = Distribution

if 'script_name' not in attrs:
    script_name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
if 'script_args' not in attrs:
    script_args = sys.argv[1:]
```

Comment: That's an error in *Python core*, if that. What version of Python 2.7 is this? The lines for `core.py` don't match any release of 2.7 that I can find, and I checked from alpha 1 all the way to 2.7.11.

Comment: That line *should* read `klass = attrs.get('distclass')` for all 2.7 releases (although the exact line number shifts around a bit), so it looks like your Python install is corrupted or altered in some way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, @ snakecharmerb, see update for answers to your questions

Comment: @BioGeek: see the [correct 2.7.3 revision](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.3/Lib/distutils/core.py#l94); your install has been altered, or incorrectly upgraded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martijn Pieters correctly deduced in the comments, my Python install got somehow corrupted. I installed the latest version of Python (2.7.11) and now everything works fine.